# Is there a documentation of what is contained in web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net

Providing support to application that runs on ASP.NET framework reads application level web.config file.
I know apart from this there are is machine level web.config and another one.
Sometimes customers make changes to machine level web.config for some reason.
Is there a complete documentation of each configuration/parameter available in web.config explained somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN - [ASP.NET Configuration File Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zeshe0eb.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

These might help -

[Format of ASP.NET Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7%28VS.71%29.aspx)

[ASP.NET Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719558%28VS.71%29.aspx)

[ASP.NET Web.config File Explained](http://dotnetrobert.com/dotnet/DotNetBlog/tabid/83/EntryID/6/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's possible to add [custom configuration sections](https://web.archive.org/web/20211027113329/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020707-1.aspx) to a web.config file, there is no such thing as complete documentation.

Comment: Agreed. IIS 7 settings can even be added into web.config files. :)